# Is it possible to use YouTubePlayer-Swift in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, swift, media-player

I need to use this https://github.com/kieuquangloc147/YouTubePlayer-Swift library in Objective-c, is it possible? If yes, can you send instruction? I am just kind of beginner in objective-c, so i dont know how can i use it. Thank you in advance!

P.S. can you recommend any other youtube or media players? I need to play Youtube or Instagram videos in my app. User shouldn't control player. I need to use media player that will play videos from url by itself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I believe your question isn't a very on-topic programming question. Rather than asking for instructions to solve the problem _for you_, give the community hints what you've tried and what did and did not work instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use official YouTube Player from Google
https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

All things are explained here -
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Yes it's Objective C library which works on Swift as well.